# Не могу понять задачу по JS

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему результат получается 8, объясните пожалуйста.

```js
var a = 1,x;
x = ++a + ++a;
x +=a;
console.log(x); // 8
```

Comment: Я так понял, вам помог ответ.  Примите его.

Comment: Да да отличный ответ, спасибо

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. В самом начале мы присваиваем переменной `a` значение **1**.
2. После этого производим 2 раза [инкремент](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#inkrement-dekrement) (в вашем случае используется префиксная форма):

   - первый `++a` — увеличиваем `a` на 1, получаем **2**,
   - второй `++a` — увеличиваем `a` на 1, получаем **3**,
   - складываем получившиеся значения, получаем **5** и записываем это значение в переменную `x`.
3. Запись `x += a` эквивалентна `x = x + a`, `x` у нас равна **5**, `a`, после последнего инкремента, равна **3**. В итоге и получаем значение **8**.

Также стоит упомянуть, что [приоритет](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) префиксного инкремента/декремента выше, чем у оператора сложения, поэтому инкремент выполнится раньше, чем суммирование.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!